# Return dictionary from generic list view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return a dictionary from list generic view. However, nothing is displayed.

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Application, Device


class ApplicationView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'applications/applications.html'
    context_object_name = 'applications'

    context = {
        "applications": Application.objects.all(),
        "devices": Device.objects.all(),
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.context
```

In template:

```
{% if applications %}
<ul>
{% for application in applications %}
<li>{{ application.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No applications found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context` isn't a field that gets used, you should put it in a [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) function instead

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['applications'] = Application.objects.all()
    context['devices'] = Device.objects.all()
    return context
```

Comment: should i keep the class?

Comment: @Andd - I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I am using a generic class based view. Your code only show a function. I am new to Django

Comment: @Andd - This is a function to include inside of your class instead of your `context` field.